# Unable to update wise installer package with wix installer

Tags: wix

I have a msi setup file which was created with wise for windows installer. Now I want to create a new version of this installer with Wix toolset. The problem is, that the installer detects the previous installed (wise created) version, but isn't able to upgrade it. I get the following error message:

"Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel"

I set the same upgrade code in both installers and chacnged the product code and the package code in the wix project. I set the upgrade informations as follows:

```
<!-- Upgrade information -->
<Upgrade Id="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
    <UpgradeVersion Property="NEWPRODUCTFOUND"
                  IncludeMinimum="no"
                  Minimum="$(var.ProductVersion)"
                  OnlyDetect="yes"/>

    <UpgradeVersion Property="OLDPRODUCTFOUND"
                  IncludeMinimum="yes"
                  Minimum="0.5.0"
                  IncludeMaximum="no"
                  Maximum="$(var.ProductVersion)"/>

    <UpgradeVersion Property="NEWERVERSIONINSTALLED"
                  IncludeMinimum="yes"
                  Minimum="$(var.ProductVersion)"
                  OnlyDetect="yes" />
</Upgrade>
```

I also tried to ensure that the product will be installed for all users by setting the InstallScope to "perMachine"

```
<Package InstallerVersion="200"
         InstallScope="perMachine"
         Compressed="yes" />
```

I have other installer projects where all versions were created with wix and for them the upgrade works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you increase the Product Version. Only newer product version can automatically upgrade the original package.

Also, please note that Windows Installer ignores the fourth version field (in case you are using it).

Comment: Yes I increased the product version. I also tried several scenarios an even increased the first version field just to make sure that this won't be the problem.

Comment: What is the old Product Version? Also, did you test this on a clean machine? Perhaps you have a broken version of the package installed on your current machine.

Comment: The old Product Version was 2.1.0.66, the new Product Version is 2.2.0.67. I also tried 3.2.0.67.